# Django: Remove message before they are displayed

Tags: django, message

I know this question sounds weird, but please, let me explain myself.

I'm using a decorator to make a message persist until the user actually dismisses it (like the behavior of stack overflow's messages). The problem is, as a result of this, the message gets added before the user signs out, and so the message gets displayed right after the user logs out. I'm wondering what the best way to remove the message in the logout view is. I've thought of two ways to do this, and am wondering if anyone can think of a better one.

I'm currently favoring this:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
storage.used = True
```

Over this:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
del storage._loaded_messages[0]
```

To me the second way seems more explicit, even though it is uglier: my intention is to remove the currently loaded messages and this makes that clear. The first way employs a means by which the messages will be cleared as a side effect ... but at least it doesn't rely upon a dunder variable ... what do you guys think?

Comment: I guess storage.used = True is implemented by default. You do not need to write it. You need to write storage.used = False if you override the default behaviour.

Comment: I ended up going with my first method. I basically wanted to force default behavior without displaying the messages. Setting storage.used = True makes it think that it's already displayed the messages, and so it worked out for me.

Comment: I agree the first method is better. If you want to make it more explicit, you could always create a function called `clear_messages` that does those two steps. Then if for some reason the behavior of `storage.used = True` changes, you can update the function.

Comment: @Jordan: I like the clear_messages function idea. Perhaps it's time for some refactoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of resolution I'm going to mark the method I went with as "The Answer". Thanks to those who commented.

I went with this:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
storage.used = True
```

Because it seemed cleaner, was easier to test, and conformed with the general practices of the rest of the project.

Answer (score 9):

I had to use 2 of the solutions proposed above *toghether* as no one alone was enought:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for _ in storage: 
    pass

if len(storage._loaded_messages) == 1: 
    del storage._loaded_messages[0]
```

As far as the accepted solution I can loop over the messages several time 
and I see that the messages don't seem to be "consumed"

Comment: I also wasn't getting the other solutions to work, but this one worked for me. I left out the `for _ in storage...` part and that worked fine (using Django 2.2.6).

Answer (score 8):

I like this simpler approach for clearing out the underlying iterator, since I actually wanted to add a new message in the place of a standard Django message.

```
list(messages.get_messages(request))
```

Comment: This is not working for me in latest django version

Answer (score 2):

If your logout view always redirects to a "logout page", then you can just change your logout template to hide your messages.

e.g., in template:

```
{% block extra-header %}
<style type="text/css">
    #message-id { display: none; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

It feels a little 'hacky' but I think it's certainly less hacky than your #2.

Comment: Cool. I hadn't thought of that approach, but project-wide the logic controlling the display of messages is separate from the template code. Also, it seems to me that the first method is easier to test.

Comment: You could also wrap the message display logic in a `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` if you don't ever want to display messages to anonymous users.

Answer (score 2):

For me in `Django 1.5` and `session` message storage accepted method dit not the trick.

I needed to use:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for _ in storage:
    pass
```

To get rid of messages from storage.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing the same thing in *Django Admin* (tested with `Django==1.11.6`) is to override `response_post_*`.

```
def response_post_save_change(self, request, obj):
    storage = messages.get_messages(request)
    storage._loaded_messages = []

    return super().response_post_save_change(request, obj)
```

And if you want to keep only your custom messages (e.g. added in `save_model` or any other overridden method) remove the last queued message (which is the one Django ads by default).

```
def response_post_save_change(self, request, obj):
    storage = messages.get_messages(request)

    if len(storage._queued_messages) > 1:
        del storage._queued_messages[-1]

    return super().response_post_save_change(request, obj)
```